# Understanding Keynote interface: View Controller > subview nav controller > table view embedded in the nav?

Tags: swift, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, subview

I'm trying to learn new UI techniques in Swift/iOS and I'm wondering if anyone can tell me what they think is happening in this UI from iOS Keynote.

[image]

When the "paint" icon is selected at the top of the view controller, it allows the user to change the format of the selected text block. What looks like a table view then slides up from the bottom. And within this table view, clicking a cell behaves like the table view is inside a navigation controller. For example, clicking the "Font" cell seems to do a "show" segue on just the table view, and it shows another table view with a "< Back" style "< Text" bar button item in the upper left of this lower view, just above the "table view". Same thing when scrolling down and clicking "Color" (this seems to segue to a different view controller embedded in a navigation controller that's inside the lower half of the device-sized view controller).

I understand how to implement what we see in the bottom half if it were a full, device-sized view controller, but I've never seen a sample project with a navigation controller that appears as a subview inside of a larger view controller. If this is what I'm seeing, then I'm unsure how to implement it (sorry if I'm missing something obvious in the Interface Builder). Is this what is happening, and if so, how does one achieve this technique? Or if it's something else, what do you suppose is the hierarchy for this UI? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: When it’s present, does it prevent interaction with the upper part of the screen?

Comment: Yes. The text block selected and showing handles is the one changed by the view at the bottom.